# more power for windows and video render

Tags: video, virtual-machine, adobe-after-effects, cloud-computing, dedicated-server

I have 10 different project on 5 windows machine that render a video with after effect, I already have a software that schedule my render.

What i need is to make more video, I would like to know what options i can have.

Would it be possible to get more CPU power from some cloud service?

An hosting service suggest me a dedicated PC with 10 virtual machines, I'm wondering if a standard machine would render the video in 1 minute 10 instances would it render 10 videos it in about 10 minutes ( or more ) each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using cloud services to bolster your CPU performance is possible but bloated. To render the videos you would need an extremely fast network connection to constantly upload and download each individual file to cloud get it rendered there and then download it. Cloud computing would be more useful if you where executing simple commands on a large amount of data. Your best option would probably be to upgrade your PC, An Intel i7 and 24 GB of RAM should be able to render your videos at a sufficient speed.

> An hosting service suggest me a dedicated PC with 10 virtual machines, I'm wondering if a standard machine would render the video in 1 minute 10 instances would it render 10 videos it in about 10 minutes ( or more ) each?

This is only in theory in reality it would take much longer to upload/download/retrieve and piece together the files.

Comment: In case of the hosting they would have a dedicated server with windows and after effect in their farm, we should just download the video when finished rendering them.

Comment: Unless your using something like Google Fiber I'm not sure if this is obtusely helpful, an average  Youtube video, uses a data rate of 2megabits per second for 720p video. An hour of video has 3600 seconds, so that's 7200 megabits, which is 900 megabytes of video. Bluray disks on the other hand often use much higher rates, such as 10 or even 25mbps which would take 4.5 gigabytes and 11.25 gigabytes respectively. With an average household connection being at 5mbps and that speed periodically dropping it would take you an awful long time to get any meaningful video done.